# How to calculate lunar phase using pyswisseph

Tags: python, tuples

Hello I'm working on astrology software but I have a problem

```
def solar_longitude(jd):
  """Solar longitude at given instant (julian day) jd"""
  data = swe.calc_ut(jd, swe.SUN, flag = swe.FLG_SWIEPH)
  return data[0]   # in degrees

def lunar_longitude(jd):
  """Lunar longitude at given instant (julian day) jd"""
  data = swe.calc_ut(jd, swe.MOON, flag = swe.FLG_SWIEPH)
  return data[0]   # in degrees
def lunar_phase(jd):
  solar_long = solar_longitude(jd)
  lunar_long = lunar_longitude(jd)
  moon_phase = (lunar_long - solar_long) % 360
  return moon_phase
print(lunar_phase(2455027.75138))
```

output---

```
    moon_phase = (lunar_long - solar_long) % 360
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'tuple'
```

Please help with this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://astrorigin.com/pyswisseph/pydoc/index.html) `calc_ut()` returns "tuple of 6 float, and returned flags", so when you take `data[0]` you're still getting a tuple. You probably want `data[0][0]` instead.